# What's a nil-nil score in Spanish for football?

Tags: deportes

What do you call a nil-nil score in Spanish for football?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to ask this on a Spanish language site?

Comment: Agree that this question will likely get closed because it is off topic here, https://context.reverso.net/traduccion/espanol-ingles/cero+a+cero

Comment: I think you need to clarify whether you just want a direct translation or whether you are asking whether Spanish has a special phrase like nil-all draw.

Answer (score 4):

"*Empate a cero*" or "*cero a cero*" are common.